# Drupal External PHP Ajax Request Error

Tags: php, ajax, drupal

So I feel like this might be something simple that I am missing, and I have searched for a while to figure out what is wrong but no luck so far. So thanks in advance for your help.

I have a fully functional php web application that includes a js file which uses simple ajax calls to get information from an external php file.

```
$.ajax({
     url:'loadlevels.php',
     type: "POST",
     dataType:'json',
     async: false,
     data: ({level: 'loadCategory', value: value}),
     success: function(data){
            fillCategory(data);//get the data for category contents
            if (bookmarking === false) {
                TargetPieceLoader( $('#categorySelect div li.category-selected') );//Next level of function called
            }
            getSliderCategory(); //
            changeCategoryArrowColor(); //call Css arrow features
        }//success function
    });//ajax call
```

We did not integrate it directly into Drupal since we want the code to be able to be in a format compatible with other programs we are planning to incorporate it with in the very near future.

The loadlevels.php page get loaded according to Chrome's dev tools Network feature. 
This script returns JSON data that should return some html that is read in the correct format for the original php file.  This works great. And is supposed to return as shown when I look at the response under the Network->Response tab in the dev tools:

```
{"stringfront":"<div id='pre-k-cat-front' style='display:block;position:absolute;z-index:10;position:inherit;margin-left:25px;'><div class='swiper-container-category'><div class='swiper-wrapper'><div class='swiper-slide'><li class='category-selection category-selected' id='cat0' value='4'><a href='javascript:;' id style='background:none;'>LETTER KNOWLEDGE<\/a><\/li><\/div><div class='swiper-slide'><li class='category-selection ' id='cat1' value='5'><a href='javascript:;' id style='background:none;'>RHYMING<\/a><\/li><\/div><div class='swiper-slide'><li class='category-selection ' id='cat2' value='6'><a href='javascript:;' id style='background:none;'>ALLITERATION<\/a><\/li><\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div>"}
```

However, the 'loadlevels.php' shows that it is being run in the Network tab on the click of the associated button that calls this ajax function, the Response  tab is empty therefore, I am not getting any data back, not even simple echo calls when I call it.

This works perfectly fine running on my local machine, but as soon as I moved it to Drupal it seemed to break, EVEN THOUGH everything is linked to the associated file via an include statement on the correct Drupal node as shown:

```
<?php include "./sites/**********/library.php"; ?>
```

I can't figure out how it is breaking at this point.  I am assuming there is some kind of Drupal feature or lack of module or function etc. that is preventing it from being accessed or something of the like.

Comment: This should work on a drupal site without a problem. You don't need any special module or function for a jquery ajax call to function. Are you sure there are no errors on the page.

Comment: There are no errors that are logged on the page, and it looks now that the ajax statement runs, but the php is not running correctly.  I used a test script to get loaded by the ajax statement which returned the ajax success statement, but didn't echo the php like it should have.  Here was what I wrote: <?php
$var = $_POST['value'];
echo json_encode("This is a value: $var");
?>

Comment: removed as I read the above wrong

Comment: Where you say "This works perfectly fine running on my local machine, but as soon as I moved it to Drupal it seemed to break, EVEN THOUGH everything is linked to the associated file via an include statement on the correct Drupal node as shown:" concerns me. What makes you think you can just include it on a node page?

Comment: I will post an answer detailing how to create a module that will return JSON

Comment: "What makes you think you can just include it on a node page?"  So in the past, this has worked for us just fine.  In working with some other smaller projects that simply echo out return statement strings with php files everything works great.  I think the problem lies probably in the php file that we use to get information to return.  That's all I can think of.  What is strange is that it works outside of Drupal, and small scripts that I include such as the one listed above work perfectly fine. Something else must be conflicted.

Comment: I am not quite sure how you have included it on a node page and had it work. But anyway, the problem with that is that Drupal  will do all the processing for that page when all you want it to do is return some simple JSON. The answer below (only 2 functions in a module) is a better approach.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll implement this and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy to create a module to return json.
Your module must have both a .info file and a .module file as with any other module.
Put something like this into your **.info** file.

```
name = My Module Name  
description = Returns some JSON.  
core = 7.x
```

Your **.module** file will need.
**1**. To implement HOOK_menu():

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['loadlevels'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'loadlevels_function',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

**2**. Return JSON from the loadlevels function.

```
function loadlevels_function() {
  // do stuff here such as check $_POST['level'] and return the results.
  // return can be an object or array or whatever.
  results = array('testing', 'testing again');
  drupal_json_output($result);
}
```

**That is it**, you should now be able to navigate to 'loadlevels' and see the result as a JSON object in the browser or get it via ajax as below.

```
$.ajax({
     url:'loadlevels',
     dataType:'json',
     data: ({level: 'loadCategory', value: value}),
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log(textStatus);}
});
```